# How to control windows in windows 10 with python3

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto, pyautogui

I am looking for a good way to get window information to find and close them programmatically.

i have been using pywinauto and pyautogui. brining all of my knowledge from autoit.

Using python3 autoit has not been working.

From Python3 we hope to accomplish: Here is the AutoIT command to translate to python3

```
If WinExists("WindowName") then
    WinClose("WindowName")
```

Comment: What is the problem? Is the window not closed? Any errors? Is your windows actually called `WindowName`? There may be things like double spaces, em-dashes, national alphabet and such. Did you get the window name from `Au3Info` tool? Does `MsgBox(0,0,WinExists('InsertYourActualWindowNameHere')` produce anything? What is the window like - tool window, child window, borderless window? Does `Alt+F4` close the window properly? What does python have to do with any of this? Please describe the problem as verbosely as possible.

Comment: Is this is a question on how to do it with python or autoit or autoit script started from python script?

Comment: Sorry, it is a poorly worded question I suppose. I want to Perfrom these action in python3. 

Python offers a few extra libraries that made the data processing for this program eaiser so the boss decided to move from AutoIT to Python3. We use pywinauto and pyautogui, but the program we are accessing doesnt always have window classes, Just a title. Im just a little lost on the control aspect. These are child window popupws.

Comment: The above code in Autoit works great... But not in python 3... That I have found. We tried calling the control from as an executable kind-of like a detect function, but it just seemed to hacky. and cumbersome. If the machine takes to long the software times out, so quicker the better.

Comment: Ok, then please edit your question to clarify all that. You will need to post some python code that you tried and which didn't work, and how exactly it failed (which parts work and which didn't, error messages, etc). You should also test the code extensively before posting on other windows and such, try at least several methods of doing what you want that you can think of. And please remove `AutoIt` tag since this has nothing to do with autoit at all (I've come here via this tag and am no expert in python, especially pywinauto)

Comment: This is better but you probably shouldn't expect python developers to start researching what autoit is and how it works. Instead remove all mentions of AutoIt and try to describe what exactly you want to happen in plain English. You will still need to provide examples of your code and error messages which result from it. And please (proof)read your own question out loud before posting - line `Using python3 autoit has not been working.` makes no sense at all. This guide may help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JackWhite Thanks for your support. I ended up finding the answer after much trial and error, and extensively reading the pywinauto docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all your help everyone, I seem to have found a good solution. Hopefully this will help someone else as well!

This connects the application to Pywinauto:

```
import pywinauto as pwa
app = pwa.application.Application(backend="uia")
app.connect(path='AppName.exe')
```

Here we are creating a dialog for the app window and specifying a name reference.

```
dlg = app.window(title_re=".*AppName.*")
```

In this area, we are calling the window, and wait for it to be ready. Then we are going to close the window.

```
dlg.child_window(title="WindowName", control_type="Window").wait('ready', timeout=10):
dlg.child_window(title="WindowName", control_type="Window").close()
print("Window is closed")
```

Comment: Good. Please accept your own answer and correct answer for other question if it resolves your problem. It's considered polite on StackOverflow. Accept check box is located under voting buttons, it should work despite of gray color.

Comment: Thank you @VasilyRyabov.